# Reduce file size of a plot (R) (plotly)

Tags: r, filesize, r-plotly, ggplotly

I've created a map in R using ggplotly. To create a link, it needs to be 524kb or under, but it currently is 1.2Mb. Are there any good ways of reducing file size so I can export it? Or is this totally unrealistic?

Comment: See my answer below. One of the bottlenecks in your map may be that it's simply generated with too many points. If this is the case, reducing the number of points used to generate the map will result in a smaller file, perhaps even under the 524kb threshold you're aiming for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your map has polygons, consider `rmapshader::ms_simplify()`, which uses the [Visvalingam algorithm](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/simplify/) to reduce the number of points used to construct a polygon.

Here's a reproducible example:

```
p  <- raster::shapefile(system.file("external/lux.shp", package = "raster")) # load data
p2 <- rmapshaper::ms_simplify(p, keep_shapes = TRUE) # simplify polygons
```

Now visualize the result:

```
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
plot(p,  main = paste("before:", object.size(p),  "bytes"))
plot(p2, main = paste("after:",  object.size(p2), "bytes"))
dev.off()
```

[image]

You can edit the default settings on the `keep` argument, lowering the number of points to retain, and thus further reducing your object size. This comes at the cost of a coarser image.

Comment: Thanks, Rich!  This is exactly what I was looking for.